# Meteor: insert produces multiple entries

Tags: mongodb, meteor, insert, callback, call

My Question is the following.

I'm starting working with meteor and wrote some small code against meerkat.

I'd like to insert the users into my database. I first have to call meerkat with the username for the meerkatId and then can get the user info.

This is my code.

```html
Users = new Mongo.Collection("users");


if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.body.helpers({
  users: function () {
      // Otherwise, return all of the tasks
      return Users.find({});
  }

});

Template.user.helpers({
  parentUsername: function (parentContext) {

      return parentContext.info.username;
  }
  
});

  
Template.body.events({
  "submit .user-search": function (event) {
    // This function is called when the new task form is submitted
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call("removeAllUsers");
    Meteor.call("searchUser",  $("#username").val() );


    //event.target.text.value = "";
    // Prevent default form submit
    return false;
  }

});



Template.user.events({
  "click .getUserBroadcast": function () {
    // Set the checked property to the opposite of its current value
    Meteor.call("getUserBroadcasts",  this._id, this.meerkatId );
  }
});

   
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    Users.remove({});
  });
}


Meteor.methods({
    searchUser: function (username) {
    HTTP.call("PUT", "https://social.meerkatapp.co/users/search?v=2",
          {data: {"username": username}},
          function (error, result) {
            if (!error) {
               content=JSON.parse(result.content);
               Meteor.call("getUserInfos", content.result[0]);
            }
          });

  },

  getUserInfos: function(meerkatId){
       HTTP.call("GET", "https://resources.meerkatapp.co/users/"+meerkatId+"/profile?v=1.0",
          {},
          function (error, result) {
            if (!error) {
               contentJson=JSON.parse(result.content);
               console.log(contentJson.result);
            
               Users.insert(contentJson.result);
            }
          }); 
  },   
  removeAllUsers: function() {
        return Users.remove({});
  }
});
```

Can someone tell me why this resolves in 3 identical User Entries (_id not of course) while getting the console output just once ?

When I do an insert in the searchUser method I get 2 Entries. I believe it's because of the asynchron callbacks.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

At a quick glance, I'm not sure about the third (though I'm guessing it's related), but with the code the way it is, is is **guaranteed** to run at least twice - once on the server and once on the client.

In the [Meteor documentation for methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods), you'll see that if you define the method on the client (referred to as a "stub") it will be **called at the same time** as the server method.  Thus, your client and server are **BOTH** doing an `HTTP.call`

You want to put the methods into a `Meteor.isServer` conditional so it gets called just once.

*If you want*, you can put a *separate* `searchUser` method definition inside a `Meteor.isClient` block, but don't put the `HTTP.call` inside there or anything else you want the server to do).  In this case, it will be defined as a stub, and will return immediately instead of waiting for the results from the server.  You can do this to simulate an a result from the server if you know what it's going to be.

You're probably best to just trigger a loading spinner (or something) when the `Method.call` is executed and update the results with a callback from the server, ala...

```
Method.call("methodNameOnServer", function clientCallback(results) { // do something. });
```

Hope this helps!